# Make the plastic cat flap clear again?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I used something on the clear plastic cat flap to clean something sticky and lasting off and the clear plastic is now cloudy.  Is there anything I can use on the clear plastic to restore it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.